# Limit scope of vlocity state model

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to use the Type Name/Type Value fields on the vlocity State Model record to control which records the model is to be applied to (they are contract records, in this case)  Properly configured, the state model manifests on the page as a path.  (see [help document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=ind.os_configure_the_type_field_180211.htm&type=5) for a description of type and its use in state models).   I have tried the following:

1. using a picklist field called Type__c
2. using a picklist field called Unique_Type_Picklist__c
3. using a text field called Unique_Type_Text__c
4. entering the field label as the value of Type Name
5. entering the field API name as the value of Type Name
6. regardless of the approach taken, the affect of populating the Type fields (Name, Value) on the state model record is to suppress the path component of the related page (in this case Contract).  (Not the desired outcome)
7. the path component promptly reappears if I clear the type fields.

Does anyone have a solution for this?